# JavaScript dynamically updated template compatible with Chrome App CSP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js, template-engine, google-chrome-app

I know of exactly one JavaScript template engine that automatically updates the page when the model changes and that's also compatible with the Content Security Policy enforced for Chrome Apps (packaged apps): AngularJS. However, AngularJS is much more than just a template engine. I'm looking for something much lighter-weight. KnockoutJS would be perfect, if only it worked for Chrome Apps.

Sandboxing the templated page is out of the question for my purposes.

Does anyone know of an alternative to AngularJS for this purpose?

UPDATE: Just came across Distal, which seems to be CSP compliant. It's not as dynamic as AngularJS (with its $watch facility), but with Distal you can at least re-render just small fragments of the page when the model changes. The link is: https://code.google.com/p/distal/

UPDATE #2: Been using Distal with WatchJS, with much success.

Comment: Whether a template engine is compatible with Chrome Apps' CSP is hardly a matter of opinion. In the case of AngularJS, were I to ask about it, someone might answer that I need to use an ng-csp directive. That's the sort of factual answer I'm looking for.

Comment: "out of the question": why? We're interested in gathering use cases where sandboxing is impossible (vs. extra work).

Comment: I am developing tutorial applications that use the Chrome App APIs, and I don't want to complicate them with the messaging that's required to interface sandboxed code to those APIs. That is, I'm trying to assemble a toolbox of Chrome-App-compatible tools.